# SQLAlchemy how to get Column values from association table in many to many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I have Playlist and Tracks class and assigned Foreign keys to playlistsTracks. all ok when want to get Playlist tracks i use playlist.tracks. But now i need to also get the 'id' of the playlistsTracks. How can i get the 'id' or any extra column from association table?

```
playlistsTracks = db.Table('tbl_test_playlisttracks',
                    db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
                    db.Column('playlist_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tbl_test_playlists.id', ondelete='CASCADE')),
                    db.Column('track_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tbl_tracks.id'))
                    )



class Track(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'tbl_tracks'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(255))
audio_url = db.Column(db.Text)
movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
entry = db.relationship('Playlist', secondary=playlistsTracks, backref=db.backref('tracks', lazy='dynamic'))



class Playlist(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'tbl_test_playlists'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(255))
user_id = db.Column(db.String(255))
current_rev = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
```

Comment: Refer http://pythoncentral.io/sqlalchemy-association-tables/. It has same scenario explained for accessing extra-data from association table.

Comment: Awsome after scratching my head for hours with this article finally i solved my problem and got whatever i wanted to get. thanx buddy.

Comment: @ZohaibGhafoorBaloch it'd be great if you could your solution here

Answer (score 1):

```
db.session.query(playlistsTracks).join(Track).all()
```

or

```
db.session.query(playlistsTracks.c.id).join(Track).all()
```

The same for the other entity Playlist

Comment: Would you pls add an explanation

Comment: In SQLAlchmey the table Class differs from an Model class. So, if you want to join a Table class (the associative table) with one Model class just join and the sql alchemy will use the foreign key associated with the two tables.
The seconde example is just showing how to filter the column "id" of the associative table as requested in the question.